# How can I monitor a TCP port for packets and timeout if none is received?

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm creating a test client with using python to test my server. It sends TCP data packets to a server, which *should* send back 1 response to the client in the same TCP connection. If it does not send any response, or sends more than 1 response, then I have a bug in the server code.

What I want to do is to monitor the TCP port for response message(s) and print them out. If there is no response, the script should carry on execution after a timeout.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import socket
import time
import multiprocessing


def get_response(response_stream, response_buffer_size):
    response_count = 1
    while True:
        response = response_stream.recv(response_buffer_size).decode()
        print("[response]", response_count, ":", response)
        response_count += 1

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.101'
TCP_PORT = 12345
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = b"Bazinga!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE.encode())

print("Message sent.")

p = multiprocessing.Process(target = get_response(s,BUFFER_SIZE))
p.start()
p.join(3)

if p.is_alive():
    print("Killing thread ...")
    p.terminate()
    p.join()

s.close()
print("Socket closed.")
```

So it turns out that `p.join(3)` is never reached because the code is stuck inside `get_response` at this line : `response = response_stream.recv(response_buffer_size).decode()`.

The script will always wait there to decode the next packet, hence the script never terminates properly. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you on windows or unix?  There is a function that's restricted to unix you could use.

Comment: Also, what version of Python?

Comment: Client is python 3, on windows. The ability to run the same code on linux would be a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

First, this line:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target = get_response(s,BUFFER_SIZE))
```

Is actually calling `get_response` *on the main thread*.  Since, you're not passing a function name like you should, but calling the function and passing the `target` argument, the result of that call.

Instead you want

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_response, args=(s,BUFFER_SIZE))
```

**But this won't work!**  You can't easily pass a socket to a different process.  There are ways around it with pipes, but the implementation is only there for Unix or Python3 on Windows.

So consider the different approach I list below.

Third, you might want to add something that breaks out of the infinite loop inside your child process function.  I added a line to check if `recv` returned an empty string, you could modify it to your liking.

Consider:

```
import socket
import time
import multiprocessing


def worker(tcp_ip, tcp_port, response_buffer_size):
    MESSAGE = b"Bazinga!"

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((tcp_ip, tcp_port))
    s.send(MESSAGE.encode())
    print("Message sent.")

    response_count = 1
    while True:
        response = s.recv(response_buffer_size).decode()
        if len(response) == 0: break
        print("[response]", response_count, ":", response)
        response_count += 1
    # If we got here, the connection was closed
    s.close()
    print("Socket closed.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TCP_IP = '192.168.1.10'
    TCP_PORT = 12345
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(TCP_IP, TCP_PORT, BUFFER_SIZE))
    p.start()
    p.join(3)

    if p.is_alive():
        print("Killing thread ...")
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
        print("Thread terminated.")

    print("Goodbye.")
```

Here, we put *all* socket activity in the worker thread.  It owns and opens the socket, sends the "Bazinga" and handles responses.

Comment: The test client should monitor a single TCP connection for N seconds, for any number of responses. More than 1 response means the server is doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi, could you share how to achieve a similar effect with pipes ?